# Trying jsoup: getting "cannot find symbol" when I just declared it the line before

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I need to find a value in an html table, so right now I'm trying to get the hang of JSoup.

I'm trying to use implement this code: http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/dom-navigation

The first two lines I've implemented, but the third one (Element content = doc.getElementById("content");) causes an "error: cannot find symbol. symbol: variable doc. location: class testparse).

Here is my code:

```
import org.jsoup.*;
import org.jsoup.nodes.*;
import java.io.*;


public class testparse {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    try
    {
    File input = new File("abc.htm");
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8", "");
    }
    catch(IOException exc){
      System.out.println(exc);
    }


    Element content = doc.getElementById("content");


  }
}
```

All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Look into variable scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scope of the variables is within the try block:

```
try
{
    File input = new File("abc.htm");
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8", "");
}
```

To fix, declare the variables outside:

```
File input = null;
Document doc = null;

try
{
    input = new File("abc.htm");
    doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8", "");
}
```